# What is this stainless-steel item's intended use? Is it a cheese grater?

Tags: equipment

Found in a drawer. I did a google image search but that turned up either handheld graters (but with *clearly abrasive grating surfaces*) or shower heads.
What irritates me is the surface seems to be not abrasive enough to be useful for grating anything.
It could be for grating poatatoes into a fine starchy slurry?
The make is WMF. It is ca. 30cm long

[image: full view]
[image: detail view]

(We are trying to downsize our kitchen stuff and I would like to know what it is so I can decide if it needs to go or if I would like to use it.)

Comment: Maybe use it for making spaetzle?

Comment: those are damn expensive, don't toss!  eek !

Comment: This is, of course, solved, but I was going to comment that this looks like the thing I put at the opening of my meat grinder to determine how finely the meat is outputted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a [parmesan cheese grater](https://www.cutleryandmore.com/wmf-profi-plus/stainless-steel-parmesan-cheese-grater-p117265).  The idea is that for a dry, crumbly cheese the flat holes work well enough.  The one time I used one I didn't find it to be terribly effective, which is probably why they're no longer made.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for the quick identification. I will try it out on some unsuspecting chunck of parmesan and see if it crumbles satisfactorily.

Comment: it seems quite an old design, I guess even the oldest of today's parmesan is unsuspecting to be rubbed against this :). In any case, @Martin please let us know how it went

Comment: Huh. I would have expected it to be some sort of spatula or something.

Comment: @Martin If it doesn't work well, repurpose it as a way to warm a pastry over a cup of coffee.

Comment: I have a hexagonal box-grater with one side very similar looking to that.  I never found it to be at all useful, even on parmesan cheese - at least 2 of the other sides work better for that purpose - maybe I've just got the wrong kind of parmesan?  I thought it was more for some kind of bleu cheese (not really my thing), but I feel like the other sides of the grater would still be better for that as well.

Comment: Darrel: no, I think it's just a bad design.

Comment: The only potential advantage is that it seems like it would be hard to grate your fingertips the way a microplane will.

Comment: use it to make Halušky! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halu%C5%A1ky